# Overload resolution and user defined conversion

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

Consider the simple code :

```
struct A;
struct B {
  B(){}
  B(A const&){ }
};

struct A {
  operator int() const {return 0;};
};
void func(B){}
void func(char){}

int main()
{
func(A()); //ambiguous call oO
}
```

First of all I'm not sure if I understand everything correctly, so correct me anytime you find me wrong please.

My understanding was that that `void func(B)` should have been chosen, since argument to `func` is `A` which is class type, hence type of conversion required is "User defined conversion sequence"

Now from IBM C++ ref :

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of the following:
>
> - A standard conversion sequence
> - A user-defined conversion
> - A second standard conversion sequence

Now there are two user defined conversion present 
`B::B(const A&)` and `A::operator int (const A&);`

so the sequence are

-> `A()` -> `B::B(const A&)` -> `Standard conversion (identity conversion)`

-> `A()` -> `A::operator int (const A&)` -> `Standard conversion (integral conversion)`

since integral conversion is worse than identity conversion I thought `void func(B)` would called but still the call is ambiguous .

So please help me at which point am I wrong and why the call is ambiguous. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think feeding `B` to `func(B)` is identity, `A`->`B::B`->`func(B)` is perhaps not; should check the standard though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two conversion sequences here, `A -> B` and `A -> int` are both *user-defined* because they operate via functions which you defined.

The rule for ranking user-defined conversion sequences is found in 13.3.3.2 (N3797):

> User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either case the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`

These two conversion sequences don't contain the same user-defined conversion function, and they don't initialize the same class in aggregate initialization (since one initializes `int`).

So it is not true that one sequence ranks above the other, therefore this code is ambiguous.

Comment: So overload resolute is confused just because user defined conversion functions are not same?

Comment: @AngelusMortis yes basically

Comment: You still've a conversion function to `B` in `A`, just removing the constructor in `B` wouldn't do.

Comment: @legends2k gcc and clangs rejects the code but MS C++ accepts the code and function selected was `void func(B)`as expected by me :)

Comment: @M.M Sir doesn't the statement "if they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor" limits us in a way that -> object-of-some-class-type as a argument to some overloaded function must contain conversion functions of same type (i.e either constructor one or conversion function), since they have to be same w.r.t overload resolution. Thanks

Comment: @AngelusMortis i'm not sure exactly what you're asking , but problems like yours are typical when you have non-`explicit` `operator T()` defined, which is why that is generally discouraged

Answer (score 3):

> so the sequence are -> A() -> B::B(const A&) -> Standard conversion (identity conversion)

No! Excerpt from the standard (draft) **[over.best.ics]** (emphasis mine):

> 8. If **no** conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence is the standard conversion sequence consisting of the identity conversion (13.3.3.1.1).

`func(A())` is not identity, it's user-defined. Again from the standard, **[[conv]]**:

> For class types, user-defined conversions are considered as well; see 12.3. In general, an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1) consists of a standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion followed by another standard conversion sequence.

I think you have a misunderstanding about *Standard conversions*. They have nothing to do with user-defined types/classes. Standard conversions are only for built-in types: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, function-to-pointer conversion, integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, boolean conversions and qualification conversions. `A` -> `int` is not any of these but a user-defined conversion. The standard on user-defined conversions, **[[class.conv]]** i.e. 12.3:

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).

You have two user-defined conversion sequences of the same rank (see M.M's answer to know why), so the compiler wants you to disambiguate.

Comment: "You have two user-defined conversion sequences, and thus are of the same rank" -> I still don't understand how did you rank them same. I'd really appreciate if you explain a bit more in simple terms :)

Comment: Conversions can be categorized by ranks: Exact match, Promotion and Conversions. Both your calls fall under the third. In that, both fall under the user-defined conversion category. When two user-defined conversion sequences compete, which one to choose is defined in the standard. This part of the standard is quoted in M.M's answer.